# laravel not working on https (https ssl provided by amazon) centos 6.8 Amazon web services

Tags: apache, laravel, http, amazon-web-services, https

i have an ec2 instance and it is running on centos 6.8. after i installed LAMP and laravel using CLI.
*i edited my httpd config and added this script.*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   #ServerName laravel.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/application/public

  <Directory /var/www/html/application>
         AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
```

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
       #ServerName laravel.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/application/public

      <Directory /var/www/html/application>
             AllowOverride All
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

i tried running my web app using HTTP and HTTPS(SSL certificate using amazon certificate manager).

after running on http. it is working. but on https, the application is not working.

EDIT: 
(I USED the SSL certificate provided by amazon web services and correct me if i'm wrong, i put in on route 53 and amazon didn't provide me with certificates.) 
i also tried using Vhost port 443 with the same config. but after i restart httpd config. both http and https did not work)

Comment: Where is your vhost config for https? Normally this is on port 443.

Comment: i add vhost config for https on port 443 and after i restarted http and https, both http and https didnt work. SAME CONFIG but on 443

Comment: Could you share the config for port 443 as well? Did you also make sure you tested the config before restarting the server? There might have been a syntax error.

Comment: i edited my question sir. please correct me if i'm wrong with my config. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The VirtualHost config you've shared is just for port 80 which will be what configures your site to work over http. You also need to configure Apache to listen on port 443 for the https protocol and define your SSL keys in this file. It will want to look something like this:-

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/application/public

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/example.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/example.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/example.bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: i used the SSL certificate provided by amazon, and i imported it on route 53.

Comment: the SSL certificate provided by amazon has no .crt file and key. i only imported it in route 53 of amazon web services.

Comment: @user2739179 the port 443 config you've added to your original question won't work as you're not telling Apache where the SSL certificates/keys are like shown in my answer above. I'm not familiar with how Amazon provides SSL certificates, but presumably you need to use what they supplied to generate the crt and key files on your server and add them to the vhost config. I'm sure a Google search will quickly turn up the steps you need. :-)